# ogrinfo works on a gdb, but ogr2ogr cant open the same file gdb

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w

GDAL 2.2.3

```
ogrinfo "Source_Rock_Geochemistry.gdb"
```

produces a list of contents which is correct.
However,

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxxxx dbname=atlas user=atlas password=yyyy ACTIVE_SCHEMA=psd"  "Source_Rock_Geochemisty.gdb"
```

produces:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `Source_Rock_Geochemisty.gdb' with the following drive
rs.
  -> `JP2ECW'
  -> `FileGDB'
  -> `OCI'
  -> `SOSI'
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `DB2ODBC'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `BNA'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `NAS'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `LIBKML'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `Interlis 1'
  -> `Interlis 2'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `GPKG'
  -> `SQLite'
  -> `ODBC'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `PGeo'
  -> `MSSQLSpatial'
  -> `OGR_OGDI'
  -> `PostgreSQL'
  -> `MySQL'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
```

etc

Using OSGeo4W, and used setup to add gdal_filegdb library. I have ogr_FileGDB.dll in the gdalplugins directory.
QGIS open the gdb fine.

Comment: Make no difference.
ogrinfo "Source_Rock_Geochemistry.gdb"
INFO: Open of `Source_Rock_Geochemistry.gdb'
      using driver `FileGDB' successful.
...
5: Source_Rock_Samples (None)

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxxxx dbname=atlas user=atlas password=yyyy ACTIVE_SCHEMA=psd"  "Source_Rock_Geochemisty.gdb" "Source_Rock_Samples"

gives the same error.

Comment: Documentation for ogr2ogr implies feature class is optional, and I thought not specifying any would copy lot.This site implies it. https://github.com/nationalparkservice/places-data/wiki/Loading-a-GDB-into-PostGIS

Comment: You have typo in the latter command: Geochemisty.

Comment: Arggh!. I kinda figured it would be something simple like that but for life of me couldnt see it! Thanks very much,